# open .java file in specified eclipse project from command line

Tags: java, eclipse, file, command

`--launcher.openFile` opens file without assigning it to any project, so different features such as code assist don't work. I am actually trying to create a source file automatically and want to edit it just like I created it by default way in eclipse.

```
private void openInEclipse(File file) throws IOException {
    String eclipsePath = "G:/eclipse/eclipse-java-juno-win32/eclipse/eclipse.exe";
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{eclipsePath, file.getAbsolutePath()});
}
```

Comment: are you trying to develop some kind of IDE ???

Comment: yes, something like this

Comment: I want to load source files from server

Comment: please post some code here... it will help to understand more

Comment: from "server" ??? elaborate plz

Comment: yes, I want to try to make something like big public project. Source files will be automatically saved to the server and loaded when required by other users.

Comment: my friend post this in your question in a formatted way.. ok

Comment: sorry for slowness(bad english, real life)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the generator write the file into a directoty that is known as a source directory to eclipse. When you also enable automatic refresh in eclipse it will update it's index when you open the newly generated file with the launcher.

Comment: this way workspace is rarely refreshed, so it still opens like external file first time...