# Immediately add a new source file to an Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse

This question is a follow-up to
[open .java file in specified eclipse project from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798201/open-java-file-in-specified-eclipse-project-from-command-line), specifically to this part (see the original question for more background):

> I am actually trying to create a source file automatically and want to edit it just like I created it by default way in eclipse.

In short, I need to open an externally generated `.java` file in the Eclipse editor. 
Eclipse's auto-refresh takes up to 5 seconds to find the new file but I want to open it in maximum of 1-2 seconds.

Any pointers / ideas towards this would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the [FileSync](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/filesync) plugin for eclipse is the right thing for you. If it is not fast enough, you could [take a look at the source](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/filesync4eclipse/source/browse/) and tweak it for your needs.

Comment: "Please note, that synchronization works is only in one direction - from Eclipse to the rest of the world."

Comment: Anyway, I installed it and now synchronization is way faster then before, thanks, it's works for me.

Comment: Even though it was not supposed to, well, glad it helped ;)